# What is the relationship between csch(x) and arccsch(x)

Tags: analysis

Which one is larger, $csch(x)$ or $arccsch(x)$ on positive $x$?

I am able to show that $csch(c)=arccsch(c)$ for some $c<1$ by direct comparing $csch(1)$ with $1$. The result gives $csch(1)<1$. By definition of inverse function, the point of intersection of $csch(x)$ and $arccsch(x)$ equals to $x$. Since both $csch(x)$ and $arccsch(x)$ are strictly decreasing, can conclude that the point of intersection $x=a$ is smaller than $1$.

I attempted to compare the first derivative of $csch(x)$ and $arccsch(x)$ at $x=1$. However, I don’t think it would suggest the relation between $csch(x)$ and $arccsch(x)$, as their derivatives equal at some point, by the IVT.

I’m open to suggestions and answers. It’s my first question on Math Stack Exchange, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is your question?